# I/O pin as I2C wire

Tags: microcontroller, i2c

In my application,I need 2 I2C interfaces as I need to interface EEPROM and smartcard.

Can we use I/O pin as I2C wire? How? Is it feasible?

Comment: it's just as feasible as bit-banging serial, except in this case you have an active low, with external resistor pull up. There is a lot of communications protocol things you will have to look up though, to ensure the software driving the IO pin is clocking properly, and the IO data pin is driving/receiving according to the specs. Remember you need two pins for I2C, the clock line and the data line.

Comment: How to read relevant stuff for this technique? What is the name of this approach so that I can read about this to explore more. Sorry for this kind of question, but I want to learn this and have to implement for my application.

Comment: software serial.. controlling an IO pin to simulate/behave like serial peripherals normally do. It can be hard to get right especially if you have a lot of stuff going on in the microcontroller. As LM Croisez says, you should be able to use the single I2C bus for the two devices. I2C can handle 100+ devices as long as they each have unique addresses. The addresses are in the datasheets, and are often adjustable with external resistors.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need two i2c interfaces, because i2c is a bus, you can attach more than one slave on it.  You will access each slave by its own address (which must be different, necessarily)

Comment: It's possible, but unlikely with such different ICs, that the addresses are the same. One way to fix that issue is to use a second bus. Other ways are based on the IC itself, such as external hardware address selecting, or splitting the I2C bus clock/data signals using I2C multiplexers. But you are correct to point this part out, good work!